# Recursion to remove duplicate characters

Tags: c++, string, recursion, duplicates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void rmvdupli(string s)
{
    if (s.length() == 1)
    {
        cout << s;
        return;
    }
    char c = s.at(0);
    if (((s.substr(1)).find(c)) >= 0)
        cout << "";
    else
        cout << c;
    rmvdupli(s.substr(1));
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter the string " << endl;
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    rmvdupli(s);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```bash
*Enter the string*

*ababcdc*

*c*
```

What is the problem with the code? It seems perfectly alright but the answer is not coming!!

Comment: `string::find` returns a value of an unsigned integral type. It's always >= 0; it's physically impossible for it to be negative.

Comment: Try smaller test cases, like an empty string, single character or two characters (unique or repeated). Then, run your code in a debugger (try to find a video tutorial on that!) which should make it pretty easy to find the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code with a bit of refactoring in order to fix the bugs and improve its readability and performance. I also added another overloaded function that is significantly faster and uses 0 heap allocations. It does the same thing though but in a far more optimized way.

Here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>


// this is basically your function but is more efficient now
void removeDuplicateChars( const std::string& str )
{
    if ( str.length( ) == 1 )
    {
        std::cout << str;

        return;
    }

    const char firstChar = str[ 0 ];
    const std::string&& restOfStr { str.substr( 1 ) };

    if ( restOfStr.find( firstChar ) == std::string::npos )
    {
        std::cout << firstChar;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "";
    }

    removeDuplicateChars( restOfStr );
}

// this one is far superior to the above one
void removeDuplicateChars( std::string_view&& strView )
{
    if ( strView.length( ) == 1 )
    {
        std::cout << strView;

        return;
    }

    const char firstChar = strView[ 0 ];
    strView.remove_prefix( 1 );

    if ( strView.find( firstChar ) == std::string_view::npos )
    {
        std::cout << firstChar;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "";
    }

    removeDuplicateChars( std::move( strView ) );
}


int main( )
{
    std::cout << "Enter the string: ";
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;
    removeDuplicateChars( str ); // this calls the first overload

    std::cout << '\n';

    removeDuplicateChars( std::string_view( "ababcdc" ) ); // this calls the
                                                           // second overload

    return 0;
}
```

Sample input/output:

```
Enter the string: ababcdc
abdc
abdc
```

I would highly recommend you to ditch the 1st overload and only use the 2nd one. Not only it's faster but also supports the types `std::string`, `std::string_view`, and *C-style strings*.

Here are some useful links to improve your knowledge:
[std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)
[std::string::substr](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)
[std::string::find](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

Answer (score -1):

The below line:

```
if (((s.substr(1)).find(c)) >= 0)
```

should be changed to:

```
if (s.substr(1).find(c) != std::string::npos)
```

It basically means that `c` is found in `s.substr(1)`.

[find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns `std::string::npos` if the character is not found.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to solve this problem of yours.

What I have done is, I have replaced duplicate characters with whitespace.

if you want to remove whitespace you can find the code easily on internet.

C++ Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void RemoveDuplicateChar(string inputString)
{
    if(inputString.length() == 1){
        cout << inputString;
        cout << "\nIt has only one character";
    }else{
       int  stringLength = inputString.length();
       cout<< "Original string: ";
       cout << inputString;
       cout << "\n";
            for(int i =0 ; i<stringLength; i++){
                for(int j = i+1; j< stringLength; j++){
                    if(inputString[i] == inputString[j]){
                        inputString[j] = ' ';
                        
                    }else{
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            cout << "Duplicate character removed\n";
            cout << "New String: ";
            cout << inputString;
            
            
            
        
    }
}

int main()
{
    string input;
    cout << "Enter a string with repeated characters: ";
    cin >> input;
    RemoveDuplicateChar(input);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

Enter a string with repeated characters: ababcdc

Original string: ababcdc

Duplicate characters removed

New String: ab  cd